# Disposing controls created in xaml

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime

How are controls created by XAML code disposed in WinRT? I have created `ImageSlideShow` UserControl which uses `SempahoreSlim` and `DispatcherTimer` ( i use timer.Tick event). Should I add .Unloaded event handler to `ImageSlideShow` user control or implement IDisposable (does xaml takes care of calling .Dispose?) to release resources and events handlers - or do I need to dispose it manually like controls created in code-behind?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use `Unloaded` event of `UserControl`. In that unhook all the events, nullify the `<Image />` & set `ItemsSource` to `null` if any collection control you are using.

How to nullify image?

```
BitmapImage bitmapImage = image.Source as BitmapImage;
bitmapImage.UriSource = null;
image.Source = null;
```

Here `image` is object of `<Image />`

Also implement `IDisposable` interface. Then you need to browse the complete UI element tree, search for your `<Image />` and call `Dispose` on all of them.

For more info check out this (It's applicable to W8 also): [How to debug most common memory leaks on WP8](http://suchan.cz/2013/11/how-to-debug-most-common-memory-leaks-on-wp8/)

Comment: Wouldn't images be freed anyway by gc (just can take few seconds more) ?

Comment: No, I tested in Windows Phone 8. It had high-end background images.